# Como enlazar botones de material desing a redes sociales?

Tags: android, android-studio, url, material-design, redes-sociales

Mi problema es el siguiente, cree un menu con Material desing y no se como enlazar la url de mis perfiles a los botones que se despliegan

ABAJO DEJO MI CODIGO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="co.com.canalcnc.menumaterial.MainActivity">

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="#0085c3"
    app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="#00FF04"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_a"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/facebook"


        />
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_b"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/instagram"
        />
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_c"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/twitter"
        />



        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo suponiendo que creo yo de igual forma un boton, el codigo es relativamente simple pero lo que tienes que hacer para enlazarlo es usar tu mainactivity para poder enlazarlo ya que esto no se puede hacer solamente con xml.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
```

View.OnClickListener {

```
 private Button btn;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_navegacion);
 btn.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
 startActivity(intent);
   }
  }
```

Ahora e aqui el boton con xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
  android:id="@+id/boton_navegacion"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:text="Navegar" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Si te das cuenta en el codigo lo unico que sucede es que mandas a llamar a tu boton del xml desde tu MainActivity mediante el ID y lo unico que tienes que hacer es ponerle el evento de click para que cuando esto suceda te mande al link que pondrias dentro como te muestro en el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

**Me disculpo, no me fije que era un FloatingActionButton**, nuevamente aqui aqui te dejo un ejemplo suponiendo que creo yo de igual forma un FloatingActionButton, el codigo es relativamente simple pero lo que tienes que hacer para enlazarlo es usar tu mainactivity para poder enlazarlo ya que esto no se puede hacer solamente con xml.

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
  <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/action_fb"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Ahora la forma en la que le pondras el link sera de la siguiente forma. Todo esto tiene que ir dentro de tu MainActivity.

```
FloatingActionMenu materialDesignFAM;
FloatingActionButton1;

materialDesignFAM = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.social_floating_menu);
floatingActionButton1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_facebook);

floatingActionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent facebookIntent = getOpenFacebookIntent(MainActivity.this);
            startActivity(facebookIntent);

        }
    });
```

**Metodo del URL.**

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

    try {
        context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); //Intenta abrir FB APP
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("fb://page/376227335860239"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/karthikofficialpage")); //Abre la pagina de facebook en una pagina nueva (Navegador). 
    }
}
```

Si te das cuenta en el codigo lo unico que sucede es que mandas a llamar a tu boton del xml desde tu MainActivity mediante el ID y lo unico que tienes que hacer es ponerle el evento de click para que cuando esto suceda te mande al link que pondrias dentro como te muestro en el codigo.

Agrega este codigo a todos los botones respectivos.

Comment: Esta usando FloatingActionButton no Button.

Comment: Amigo @Jorgesys no me habia dado cuenta, diculpa pero ya esta corregido el codigo para que ahora si sea de mayor utilidad :D